# Troubleshooting Samba server connection issue

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I have a Samba server (smbd version 4.3.11) running on Ubuntu.

I cannot connect to it from other computers on my LAN (I tried an OS X 10.12 box and a Windows 7 box)

However, I can telnet to port 139 from my OS X box and see the connection in the smbd logs.  And I can connect to samba locally on the Ubuntu box.

Any ideas on further troubleshooting?

More details on what I have done so far:

The Ubuntu server is at 192.168.1.11

The OS X client box is at 192.168.1.107

I set the log level on smbd to level 3.

I run the following command on the Ubuntu server:

```
smbclient -L 192.168.1.11 -U%
```

This successfully returns the expected shares on the server and prints a large number of log lines to the smbd logs.

I run the following command on the OS X box:

```
smbutil view '//192.168.1.11'
```

I get the following error:

```
smbutil: server connection failed: No such file or directory
```

No log lines printed on the server.
Any attempt to connect to the server using the `connect to server` UI in OS X Finder fails.  Same with the `map network drive` UI in Windows 7.  No smbd log entries are posted for any of these.

I run the following command on the Ubuntu server:

```
echo hello | telnet 192.168.1.11 139
```

This appears in the smbd logs:

```
==> /var/log/samba/log.192.168.1.11 <==
[2017/07/09 03:45:41.892842,  3] ../source3/smbd/oplock.c:1310(init_oplocks)
  init_oplocks: initializing messages.
[2017/07/09 03:45:41.892955,  0] ../source3/smbd/process.c:339(read_packet_remainder)
  read_fd_with_timeout failed for client 192.168.1.11 read error = NT_STATUS_END_OF_FILE.
[2017/07/09 03:45:41.893288,  3] ../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:252(exit_server_common)
  Server exit (failed to receive smb request)

==> /var/log/samba/log.smbd <==
[2017/07/09 03:45:41.892646,  3] ../source3/lib/access.c:338(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.1.11 (192.168.1.11)
```

I run the identical command on OS X, and the following appears in the logs:

```
==> /var/log/samba/log.192.168.1.107 <==
[2017/07/09 03:47:47.151012,  3] ../source3/smbd/oplock.c:1310(init_oplocks)
  init_oplocks: initializing messages.
[2017/07/09 03:47:47.151336,  3] ../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:252(exit_server_common)
  Server exit (failed to receive smb request)

==> /var/log/samba/log.smbd <==
[2017/07/09 03:47:47.150839,  3] ../source3/lib/access.c:338(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.1.107 (192.168.1.107)
```

So, it appears the OS X box can connect to the smbd port and smbd is listening.  And smbd does appear to be properly serving requests locally, but refuses to respond to any valid remote requests.  I am at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

Does the Samba Shared Directory have the correct permissions?

A common issue with Samba is that the Shared Folder itself does not have the correct permissions. When you make your Shared Directory you should make it without Sudo. If you don't do that you will have to adjust ownership and permissions after the fact. Note Samba still does the smb sharing functions but the permissions need to be correct.

Comment: Yes, it has access to the folder.  I don't think it is relevant though.  I am just requesting a list of shares, not actually attempting to open one.  And even if I was mounting a share, I would expect a log message for the failed request.  I am logging at level 3.